# Resolution Issue in Kivy GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

I have created a GUI in Kivy. I have a `720p` resolution supported by my laptop but the GUI created by me is in `1080p`. I have tried a code for custom resolution in Kivy which is as:

```
Window.size = (1080, 1920)
```

Is there any method by which I can test this GUI in my laptop without changing the aspect ratio and GUI should be in original form only ?

Is there any method in Kivy by which I can scale whole GUI in Kivy without losing resolution ?